# Is there any way for broadcast to every channel in redis?

Tags: go, redis, broadcast

I am trying to broadcast the message to channel in redis, but every user have they'r own channel with their user_id.

the way i think can be use is get all active channel and then publish it one by one. because what i know redis can't publish if diferent channel.

but the problem is, in lib `go-redis` i am using when the user subribe and check the redis  with command `PUBSUB CAHNNELS` there is no channel result. i read on documentation the subribe function not gonna actived thhe channel immidietly. so how can i get the subribe channel ?

is there any solution to solve this ?
i am using `golang-redis` https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe each connection to the per user channel and and a channel for broadcasts. To send to all users, publish to the broadcast channel. The subscriber code will look something like this with the go-redis client:

```
sub := client.Subscribe(userChannel, broadcastChannel)
defer sub.Close()
for {
   m, err := sub.ReceiveMessage()
   ... do something with m
}
```

where userChannel and broadcastChannel are the names of Redis channels. Use code like this to broadcast:

```
cmd := client.Publish(broadcastChannel, message)
if cmd.Err() != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: so i need to create a another special channel for broadcast ?

Comment: @darmawanzulkifli Applications do not explicitly create Redis channels.  The channel is special only in that it's the one that the application subscribes all clients.  See updated answer.

Comment: thanks @CeriseLimon i will try your solution. but, I am still have confusion, whether when the user is connected and the subscribe channel client will wait until the message arrives ?

Comment: The application subscribes the connection to two channels and then goes into a loop receiving messages on that connection.  The receive operation blocks until a message is published to one of those two channels or there is an error on the connection. If you have the non-broadcast code working, adding broadcast is as simple as adding an argument to the subscribe call.

Comment: Thanks @CeriseLimón.. it's done, but there is any problem. when global channel called first, private channel not listen when sent the nessage. also when private channel called first, global channel not gonna work. did you know what happend ?

Comment: When you say that a channel is called first, are you referring to the order of the function arguments or are you actually making two function calls?